# Route update status

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to change the status but it says that the route is not defined.

It appears that the "updateStatus" route is not defined.

Below is some code snippets:

web.php:

```php
Route::get('customers/{id}/status', [CustomerController::class, 'status'])->name('customers.status');
```

CustomerController:

```php
public function status(Customer $customer)
{
    return view('customers.status', compact('customer'));
}
```

```php
public function updateStatus(Request $request, Customer $customer)
{
    $request->validate([
        'status' => 'required',
        'email'  => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($customer->status == 0) {
        $customer->status = 1;
        $customer->save();
    } else {
        $customer->status = 0;
        $customer->save();
    }

    $email_data = array(
        'nome' => $request['nome'],
        'email' => $request['email'],
    );

    Mail::send('welcome_email_customer_status', $email_data, function ($message) use ($email_data) {
        $message->to($email_data['email'], $email_data['nome'])
            ->subject('Você foi aprovado!')
            ->from('', '');
    });
        
    $customer->fill($request->post())->save();

    return redirect()->route('customers.index')->with('success', 'Status atualizado com sucesso!');
}
```

status.blade.php:

```html
<form
  action="{{ route('customers.updateStatus',$customer->id) }}"
  method="POST"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
```

Comment: is that route defined in `web.php`?

Comment: "Route [customers.updateStatus] not defined. (View: C:\breeze-app\resources\views\customers\status.blade.php)" 
I have a button called "update status" and when I click on it it gives the error

Comment: define the route in `web.php` if it is not defined

Comment: changed Route::get('customers/{id}/status', [CustomerController::class, 'status'])->name('customers.status'); to Route::get('customers/{id}/status', [CustomerController::class, 'updateStatus'])->name('customers.status'); but the error still persists

Comment: when i said u to change the route? u need 2 routes in this case. `get` (to show the view) and `post/patch/put` (to submit the form)

Comment: Route::get('customers/{id}/status', [CustomerController::class, 'status'])->name('customers.status');
    Route::post('customers/{id}/status', [CustomerController::class, 'updateStatus'])->name('customers.updateStatus'); In this way?

Comment: Please read [ask] and write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title.

Answer (score 4):

You need a route on web.php

```
Route::post('customers/{id}/status', [CustomerController::class, 'updateStatus'])->name('customers.updatestatus');
```

read this
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-parameters

You can use PUT method to update

Comment: now got the following error "Missing required parameter for [Route: customers.updateStatus] [URI: customers/{id}/status] [Missing parameter: id]. (View: C:\breeze-app\resources\views\customers\status.blade.php)"

Comment: @MatheusOliveira in your form (blade), change the route to `route('customers.updateStatus', ['id' => $customer->id])`

Comment: Change 

action="{{ route('customers.updateStatus',$customer->id) }}" 

to 

action="{{ route('customers.updateStatus',['id' =>$customer->id)] }}"

Comment: @N69S "Missing required parameter for [Route: customers.updateStatus] [URI: customers/{id}/status] [Missing parameter: id]." 
I even ran the commands to clear the caches

Comment: @AlfredoOsorio "Missing required parameter for [Route: customers.updateStatus] [URI: customers/{id}/status] [Missing parameter: id]. "
the same too

Comment: change action to <form action="{{ route('customers.updateStatus', ['id' => $customer->id]) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> and the error persists

Comment: Make some tests here, you need declare on function updateStatus variable $id. is a parameter to. 

public function updateStatus(Request $request, Customer $customer, $id)....

Comment: CustomerController: public function updateStatus(Request $request, Customer $customer, $id)

Comment: status.blade: <form action="{{ route('customers.updateStatus', ['id' => $customer->id]) }}" method="POST" >
web.php:  Route::get('customers/{id}/status', [CustomerController::class, 'status'])->name('customers.status');
          Route::post('customers/{id}/status', [CustomerController::class, 'updateStatus'])->name('customers.updateStatus'); @AlfredoOsório

Comment: <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('customers.status',$customer->id) }}">Update Status</a> index.php to call the status.blade is like this

Comment: @MatheusOliveira do the same thing for the href attribute in your  `<a >` tag

Comment: @N69S 
I tried {{ route('customers.status', ['id' => $customer->id]) }} and the error remains the same, I think it's still giving an error in status.php and not in index.php...

Comment: @MatheusOliveira keep trying to update your original question, improve your route in web.php in your original question and improve the route parameters in your original question. Then add the route to update information using your form

Comment: I already have the get and post route to make this update, but it always tells me the same error and I don't know what else it could be @UnderDog"Missing required parameter for [Route: customers.updateStatus] [URI: customers/{id}/status] [Missing parameter: customer]."

Comment: Did you update your original question with this error? It's really important that you do. Don't let the kost important thing in your problem show as a perfect error message somewhere in a comment. It should be in your question at the top of your page

Comment: Route::get('customers/{id}/status', [CustomerController::class, 'status'])->name('customers.status');
    Route::post('customers/{id}/status', [CustomerController::class, 'updateStatus'])->name('customers.updateStatus'); my routes are like this.. i don't know what it could be

Comment: my form i changed from <form
  action="{{ route('customers.updateStatus',$customer->id) }}"
  method="POST"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
> to <form action="{{ route('customers.updateStatus', ['id' => $customer->id]) }}" method="POST" >